# What is good Tcl compiler

Tags: tcl

I want to learn Tcl programming, but I`m having trouble with compile source code. I need good compiler tool. Can you help me? What compiler should I use or the best one?
 Thank you !!!!

Comment: You mention that you are having trouble. What kind of trouble? Is it that you do not have a compiler at all, or is there some problem with what you are currently using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tcl is a programming language. It has a number of implementations, but the one you are most likely to be able to get hold of is `tclsh`. Linux-based systems often have one already installed (if not, there'll certainly be a way to get it from your distribution's package repository). On Windows, the ActiveTcl distribution from ActiveState is *highly* recommended. I don't know if all MacOS X systems have it (mine did) but you are recommend to get ActiveTcl anyway as that also includes many extra useful packages for things you can do with Tcl, and is also more likely to be up-to-date.

You might also encounter the `wish` and `expect` programs; these are actually little more than `tclsh` with an extra library loaded into them and pre-activated for you. (For `wish`, that library is Tk which does GUIs, for `expect` that library is Expect which does terminal interaction.) The Tcl they include is the *same* as in `tclsh`, but has some extra commands.

When asking future questions here about Tcl, it helps a lot if you mention the exact version (as reported by Tcl's `info patchlevel` command) that is being used.

---

In terms of compilers, you don't normally need one. The implementation engine used by `tclsh` actually does dynamic compilation of your Tcl program (to a bytecode) as necessary, and is so fast that it is actually slower to load bytecodes than to recompile from scratch. (We did some tests and decided that, whatever speedups we should do, saving bytecodes were not going to be a part of the strategy as there was no point.) The only real case for using a compiler with Tcl is where you are using it to *obscure* the code, to make it hard for a user to look at and change. But the only sane scenario for that is when doing commercial apps (it's against the basic principle of Open Source Software) so if you need it, you are going to be directed to a commercial solution. (ActiveState sell such a product.) OTOH, if you're really thinking more about packaging — putting your code together in a neat parcel — then we have a different technology for that, the starkit, which is very neat indeed. But that's getting a bit further off the topic…

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux, you probably have Tcl already installed in your system. Type tclsh in the console and see if it works, or look for Tcl in the software installation tool.

If you are using Windows or MacOSX, you can download it from ActiveState [here](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

[tcl](http://tcl.tk/) is a [scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) (and, IMHO, not a particularly good one; Ruby, Python, Ocaml, Lua are better in my opinion). Its implementation is usually not compiled (perhaps some experimental implementations might use [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques). `Tk` is a graphical toolkit built above the `Tcl` interpreter.

In particular, there is no "compilation" step to use Tcl (because you don't need any "compiler" to *use* -i.e. code some scripts in- *Tcl*); you just need its [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29). (You may need a *C* compiler to build the `tcl` interpreter from its source code, you usually can install the interpreter binary; details depend upon your system).

So you just need to use your editor (e.g. Emacs, Gedit or even Notepad if you are restricted to Windows) to begin coding some *Tcl* scripts.

If you are learning to code, I strongly suggest to learn some better programming languages (e.g. *Scheme* or *Ocaml* or *Python*) before learning *Tcl*. The lack of modularity in *Tcl* will bite you quite soon!

Comment: What Should I do to start learning TCl language? (tools)

Comment: @user1276891, you should do the same that one always does when learning something new: Look for a tutorial, or a teacher, or a book. Get the necessary tools (given the links in this answer, it should be obvious where from). Then make an effort of your own, and practice. What kind of help are you expecting from us?

Comment: @user1276891 Try the [tutorial pages](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) on the main Tcl website.